# Angular Material layout add row after every 4th column

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

Is it possible to add a new row after every fourth column using Angular Material Layout/ Flex ?

We have to show these fixed width albums and show only 4 albums on a row.

This was the code we used using bootstrap

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items ng-if="$index % 4 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{ items[$index].id }} </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{ items[$index + 1].id }}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{ items[$index + 2].id }}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{ items[$index + 3].id }}</div>
  </div>
```

How can we do this using angular material ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For flex layout, check this link out : https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

You may try this script below

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items ng-if="$index % 4 == 0" fxLayout="row" fxFlex>
    <div>{{ items[$index].id }} </div>
    <div>{{ items[$index + 1].id }}</div>
    <div>{{ items[$index + 2].id }}</div>
    <div>{{ items[$index + 3].id }}</div>       
</div>
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/0Q7U6cXbI21kj42dWhNO?p=preview Do i need to give a fixed width to the inner div ?

Comment: you can add flex="25" or whatever size you want it to be. example -> <div flex="25">{{ items[$index].id }} </div>